# How to set 'Cache-control: no-store' IMB Liberty

Tags: java, open-liberty

Is there a way to set Cache-Control header for IMB Open Liberty? I've checked the documentation and I can't seem to find a clear way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

As you would do with any other servlet container, use filter.